# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, gson

I am currently using Gson with JQWidgets.

Step 1: Using gson using its api to send json data of below format to the grid as its rows supported by JQWidgets.

```
[
  { "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste", "ContactName": "Maria Anders", "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative", "Address": "Obere Str. 57", "City": "Berlin", "Country": "Germany" },
  { "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados", "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "Avda. de la Constitucin 2222", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }, 
  { "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquera", "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno", "ContactTitle": "Owner", "Address": "Mataderos 2312", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }
]
```

Step2: At the frontend on the jsp the grid row's data is changed, 
these changes are pushed as below in an temporary array.

// Here a global array is created , and the data changes
// done in each row of the grid is put into the array

```
    var tempArray = new Array();
    {
     var data = $('#jqxgridreq').jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);
     var arr = $.makeArray(data);
     tempArray.push(data);                
    }
```

and later followed is --> var json_string = JSON.stringify(tempArray); 
Here , the data is same as the sample data shown above while creating a json string.

Step3: The changed data is sent to the server as AJAX call, as below

```
[
  { "CompanyName": "IOK", "ContactName": "Maria Anders", "ContactTitle": "Sales Head", "Address": "Obere Str. 57", "City": "Berlin", "Country": "Germany" },                    
  { "CompanyName": "Dubiou", "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo", "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager", "Address": "Avda. de la Constitucin 2222", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }                    
]
```

It reaches the server side code where i wish to read it as it was sent and i get the below Error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
```

Kindly help and suggest on how to get through this issue.

Thanks and Regards
Ranchs

Answer (score 0):

> It reaches the server side code where i wish to read it as it was sent
>   and i get the below Error:

Are you converting the `String` to `JSONArray` before reading on Server Side?

like this,

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Gson excepts a key which you want to map with the POJO, something like

```
 public class Test {
    private List<Type> attr;
     }
```

and this attr has to be present in the json {"**attr**" : [
  { "CompanyName": "IOK", "ContactName": "Maria Anders", "ContactTitle": "Sales Head", "Address": "Obere Str. 57", "City": "Berlin", "Country": "Germany" },
  { "CompanyName": "Dubiou", "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo", "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager", "Address": "Avda. de la Constitucin 2222", "City": "Mxico D.F.", "Country": "Mexico" }
] }